# How to add a remote to a repository with lfs?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote, git-lfs, gitkraken

I'm trying to set up something like this: a bare repo on my HDD drive and a clone of it on my SSD with lfs installed. I'm doing it like this:

First I set up a bare repo on my HDD:

```
mkdir git_lfs_test.git
cd git_lfs_test.git
git init --bare
```

And then on my SSD:

```
git clone D:/Git/git_lfs_test.git
cd git_lfs_test
git lfs install
git lfs track '*.png'
```

After doing this I open the cloned repo in GitKraken. I make the initial commit and then commit and push the .gitattributes file. Then I create a png file (which GitKraken recognises as a lfs file) and push it to the origin. It throws this error:

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
$ git config lfs.D:/Git/git_lfs_test.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
batch request: missing protocol: "D:/Git/git_lfs_test.git/info/lfs"
exit
```

After running the line of code it suggests I still get the same error.

I'm new to git so I'm probalby making some obvious mistake, but I can't figure out what it is.

Also I want to set up my lfs cache so it is on the HDD so any help on that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and this is a partial solution.

1. Run a local dockerized lfs-server saving the data somewhere, e.g. /var/LFS/LOCAL/REPOSITORY/, change it as you like.

   docker run -d --rm -v /var/LFS/LOCAL/REPOSITORY/:/lfs -p 9999:9999 -t fjukstad/lfs-server
2. Browse the management interface at http://127.0.0.1:9999/mgmt [admin/admin]
3. Add a *user* and a *password*
4. In your git directory, add the lfs url (you might want to remove the user/password, but it will keep asking you):

   git config lfs.url http://user:password@localhost:9999/

**Problems**:

- This is not a per-branch config. Be sure that it does not affect other branches (this is my case: other branches point to a different server, so I risk missing files on such server).
- Don't know how to add ssh keys. If you do, tell us.
- The docker container should run permanently.