# How to add lfs support to this git setup?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-lfs

I've set up my git repos like this: a bare repo on my HDD and a clone of it on my SSD. The bare repo is acting as a backup. Now I want to add lfs support to it and can't figure out how. I tried doing this in the clone repo:

```
git lfs install
git lfs track '*.png'
```

Now I create `test.png` in that directory.

```
git add .
git commit -m "added png file"
git push origin master
```

After running the last line I get this error:

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
$ git config lfs.D:/Git/test.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
batch request: missing protocol: "D:/Git/test.git/info/lfs"
error: failed to push some refs to 'D:/Git/test.git'
```

Doing `git config lfs.D:/Git/test.git/info/lfs.locksverify false` doesn't help.
I think I'm misunderstanding how lfs sould be set up, but I couldn't find any tutorials on how to do it locally. I'm also not sure if it can even work without a server for lfs cache. Any help on how to set this up would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a remote to a repository with lfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295924/how-to-add-a-remote-to-a-repository-with-lfs)

Answer (score 1):

@alierdogan7: On Bitbucket, the LFS support is enabled in the repository settings (toothed wheel, lower left side)

Answer (score 0):

Although this problem is older, my answer may help people still serching for such issue:

I had exactly the same problem. 
Then I saw that LFS is not enabled in the remote project that I cloned locally.
After enbling , it seemed still not to work.
But I had only to clone (again) after enabling... pushing lfs files worked.

Comment: Could you please explain how you enabled LFS support in your project? Using which commands? I am now exactly having the same issue with you.