# Remote "Origin" does not support the LFS locking API

Tags: gitkraken

I have received the following message when trying to push a commit on GitKraken - Gitkraken - Remote "Origin" does not support the LFS locking API.

I have not idea what LFS and do not require it, please could someone tell me how to disable this?  Does it need to be done through the command line or is there an option just to disable it on the Gitkraken interface?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295924/how-to-add-a-remote-to-a-repository-with-lfs